# gblinear xgboost in R

Tags: r

Let's say that a data has both numeric & catagoricial feature, and I've created a xgboost model by using gblinear. I've analyzed the xgboost model with xgb.importance, then how can I express categorical variable weights?

Answer (score 1):

While XGBoost is [considered to be a black box](https://kaggle2.blob.core.windows.net/forum-message-attachments/76715/2435/Understanding%20XGBoost%20Model%20on%20Otto%20Dataset.html?sv=2012-02-12&se=2016-03-03T04%3A48%3A20Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=fXrUqBw3%2F78t%2BcdoEXSnirGWAfj%2BYfbis%2BWHNB%2FYScM%3D) model, you can understand the feature importance (for both categorical and numeric) by averaging the gain of each feature for all split and all trees.

This is represented in the graph below.

```
# Get the feature real names
names <- dimnames(trainMatrix)[[2]]

# Compute feature importance matrix
importance_matrix <- xgb.importance(names, model = bst)

# Nice graph
xgb.plot.importance(importance_matrix[1:10,])
```

[image]

In the feature importance above, we can see the first 10 most important features.

This function gives a color to each bar. Basically a K-means clustering is applied to group each feature by importance.

Alternately, this could be represented in a tree diagram (see the link above).